# How can I find a certain Index of a JSON array based on its content? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, database

My JSON-File is:

```
[
    {
        "date":"2022-W04",
        "moods":[
            {"mood":4,"name":"Dennis"},
            {"mood":3,"name":"Kevin"},
            {"mood":3,"name":"Alexandros"},
            {"mood":2,"name":"Tobias"},
            {"mood":0,"name":"Andreas"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "date":"2022-W05",
        "moods":[
            {"mood":0,"name":"Dennis"},
            {"mood":0,"name":"Kevin"},
            {"mood":3,"name":"Alexandros"},
            {"mood":2,"name":"Tobias"},
            {"mood":0,"name":"Andreas"}
        ]
    }
]
```

I now want to have the index for example for date 2022-W05 to access its data(mood and name).
Of course I could just loop through the entire array and check for the correct date but is there a better way to get the right index?

Comment: You still need to loop through the array and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is quite useful in your case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.